# How to show jquery message after clicking on submit button

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am new to jquery and would like to learn how to show a message (e.x please wait in green color or submitting ) after clicking on the submit button.

Can you please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be this will help:

```
$('#submitButtonID').click(function(){
 alert('Please wait while form is submitting');
 $('#formID').submit();
});
```

Comment: `.clickfunction()`? You mean `.click(function(){`

Comment: @Harmen.. Yes, typing mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

After you click on a `submit` button usually the form is submitted to the server and all client script execution stops. So unless you AJAXify your form it won't work. In order to AJAXify your form you could attach to the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event and replace the default action:

```
$(function() {
    $('#theForm').submit(function() {
        // show a hidden div to indicate progression
        $('#someHiddenDiv').show();

        // kick off AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                // AJAX request finished, handle the results and hide progress
                $('#someHiddenDiv').hide();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and your markup:

```
<form id="theForm" action="/foo" method="post">
    <input name="foo" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<div id="someHiddenDiv" style="display: none;">Working...</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Ajaxifying the form is not needed. You can just show a hidden div element during submit. As long as the server side hasn't sent any bit of the response back, the webbrowser will keep displaying the initial page.

You can use CSS `display: none` to initially hide an element. You can use [jQuery.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to show the element(s) matching the selector.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3377468</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#form').submit(function() {
                    $('#progress').show();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #progress { 
                display: none;
                color: green; 
            }
        </style>            
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" action="servlet-url" method="post">
            ...
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="progress">Please wait...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, as long as you are [not using *scriptlets* in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to run heavy business stuff, but rather a servlet class which in turn displays the JSP at end of the processing, it'll work as you expect.