# Html: Message on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I hate to ask questions like that, but i have been searching for quite a while, and i didn't find what i am looking for in either google or stackoverflow yet. I am looking for a way to show a short message on button click.
I know about alert('message');  but what i am looking for is a lot different.
When the button is clicked i want to :

- Not reload the page.
- Display a very short 1-2 line message **next to the button that was clicked**, depending on the result of a php function.
- Excecute php function

One example is stack-overflow's message you get when you try to *upvote your own question/answer/comment*.
To decide which message you get, i will have to run a php function ( which i already have made ) and depending on the `return` value of that function i will either show `message A` , or `message B`. Any suggestions/guidance to this matter is welcome.

Comment: Can you please post up any code you have written so far.

Comment: So far i have only been learning php, and basic html coding. What i am trying to do is simply show a message next to a button, when that button is clicked, depending on the result of a php function and excecute another php function. Posting the code i made won't help, since it has nothing to do with the actual question. Which is sending a pop-up message. I don't know how to code something like this. I suspect it is very simple though

Comment: @AbdulJabbar if you see the stackoverflow message on voting up your own comment , it has a small (x) button on top right corner , and also , if you click anywhere on it it closes, i dont really mind how the message will work, but id rather it to stay there , and you closing it manually , thats really minor though, im looking for the really base functionality of it

Comment: If you want to display a message depending on a PHP script, you have to use AJAX : it will go find your PHP script, and return its value wherever you want on the page, without reloading it. You should learn difference between server-side and client-side language.

Comment: @enguerranws i already got that by now enguerranws. however my question remains focused on the point:  `display a short message next to the button that was clicked` i already knew about ajax before i asked this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following functionality of TwitterBootstrap is what you're looking for:

**[See it working here](http://www.tutorialspark.com/twitterBootstrap/TwitterBootstrap_Tooltip_Javascript_Method_show.php)**

You can reposition it infront of your button and also style it according to your needs.

Comment: haha, you're welcome.. there are also plenty of other custom tooltip libraries available out there. I got the hint that you're looking for the tooltip from your message regarding "message shown on voting up your own comment on stackoverflow"

Answer (score 1):

You will have to learn ajax ( which you can do quite easily with jquery ).
Ajax allow you to send data with javascript/jquery to a server ( php script ) and get a response without reloading the page http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url, 
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});
```

this code will call your php script (url),  send data ( for example a button id or whatever ) and will return data from server ( success).

Comment: the main question i have from your answer is: how will i actually show a small message , next to my button ?

Comment: just create an empty div responseDiv in your html , and then after this code do something like responseDiv.html(success);  With success the message from your php code ( echo $message in php)

Comment: there are plenty of examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: i think your answer is super general though, no ? how will show the message `next to my button` like a pop-up message, i don't think creating an empty div covers my question

Comment: if you don't know .html() function in jquery i guess you have to learn some more, its very basic stuff

Comment: If you wanna somehting next to your button, then I guess we need to see your HTML to provide a full answer.

Comment: i mean.. if it was basic stuff, people woulda already posted working examples, something like when you click `submit` you see `successful submit` right next to the submit button . this is the basic functionality of what i am trying to do here , plus , excecuting a `<?php test(); ?>`  php function

Comment: Sometimes when it seems obvious, we really can't help : you say you know about Ajax, and you don't know about .click() and .html() method. It's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**To display a message next to your button**, assuming you're using jQuery (as all lazy people) :

```
$('#your-button').click(function(){
    $(this).next().html('Hello World :) ');
});
```

*This basically will find the element right next to the button (here #your-button) you clicked on, empty its content and replace it with Hellow World :).*

**If you need to display a message depending on a PHP script, you need AJAX**. It will be something like this :

```
$('#your-button').click(function(){
    $.get( "myscript.php", function( data ) {
       $(this).next().html(data);
       alert( "Load was performed." );
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IN this case AJAX is your friend 
You can go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377468/how-to-show-jquery-message-after-clicking-on-submit-button) and find the answer by BalusC