# Hiding a div element in a JSP when scriptlet has performed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If I have a servlet which may take several minutes to produce a response, I want to display a single message on the page saying 'Please wait...'

At the moment I have code:

```
<div id = "subHeader">                    
    <%            
        out.flush();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
           if (i == 0) {
               out.print("<h2>Please wait...</h2>");
               out.flush();
           }                        
           Thread.sleep(3000);  
        }
        out.flush();
        out.print("<h2>Results of analysis:</h2>");
    %>            
</div>
```

This prints:

`<h2>Please wait...</h2>
 <h2>Results of analysis:</h2>`

When the response is pending.

Is it possible to hide the `subHeader div` so that when the scriptlet has run and the response is made, I only see `<h2>Results of analysis:</h2>` and the rest of the page?

Comment: have it hidden by default, and keep polling for existance of particular DOM in javascript, once it is available make it visible

Comment: The problem there is that I know nothing of DOM.

Comment: even more reason to learn about it; to do this kind of stuff you pretty much have to know DOM javascript/jquery/Growl notification.Never put this kind of code in JSP file by the way.

Comment: True. But I am content to accept a quick and dirty fix here.

Comment: DOM is any element that you can serve to your HTML page once the table rendering is done, and check for its presence to decide weather to show the div now or not

Comment: Are you using any libraries at this point like Bootstrap or jQueryUI?  If so, they have modals that can be used, and then called to hide via JavaScript.    However, since you're waiting (or requesting of some sort) this is being done server-side you'd need some sort of method to PUSH to the client side when ready (btw I'm not a JSP guy).  However, if you performed the waiting on the client side in JavaScript, then it's completion could fire an event via ajax, or a timer w/ a callback, etc

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using jQuery,

```
$('#subheader').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks but where in the page or scriptlet would this call be made?

Comment: In a script tag after the results of the analysis.

Comment: Perhaps a solution like this is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377468/how-to-show-jquery-message-after-clicking-on-submit-button --> But I am happy to accept a quick and dirty solution based upon this answer for now pending a look at the link above.

Comment: I don't think that's really related. But I agree that this solution is definitely quick and dirty - it's most likely that you should redesign this so that the loading happens asynchronously.

Comment: Perhaps not. But as this is not a commercial project, I'm not too concerned. I just wanted something basic working.